# Поиск элементов по атрибуту регулярное выражение

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Получаю для обработки все элементы  у которых есть атрибут data-lang

```js
$("[data-lang]").each(function(index, element) {

  console.log(element)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="shop-input" type="text" maxlength="100" data-lang-placeholder="Filter">
<div id="shop-refresh" class="slim-content-btn noselect" data-lang="shop_refresh"></div>
```

Но у меня еще есть атрибуты data-lang-tittle и т.п.
Как их тоже захватить, пытался `$("[^data-lang]")` не выходит

Comment: я не про то ответ написал :D

Comment: Не проще ли сделать класс .data-lang для всех этих элементов?

Comment: варианта тут два: **1)** либо элементам. где будет данные имена `data-lang-*` присваивать общий класс и пробегаться используя уже именно его, **2)** либо придется пробегаться по всем элементам, и смотреть, у кого есть данный атрибут начинающийся с данной строки

Comment: Хотите сказать что в селекторе jquery нет поддержки регулярных выражений ?

Comment: @LorDo в jquery селекторы (регулярки настроены) подчиняются **точь в точь** законам селекторов в css. А в CSS такого не завезли. Можно им Issue создать, чтоб сделали))

Comment: [Клац](https://jsfiddle.net/d0feon0y/)

Comment: `$("[data-lang],[data-lang-tittle],[data-lang-title]")`

Comment: @Mr.Brightside можно было и ответ сделать

Comment: @Darth Сейчас все будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично на мой взгляд, решение ниже хуже, чем если, все же, добавить классы элементам, но тут уж автору вопроса решать:

```js
$('*').filter(function() {
    for(var prop in $(this).data()) {
      console.log(prop);
        if(prop.indexOf('lang') !== -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}).css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-lang="hello">One</div>
<div data-lang-new="hello">Two</div>
<div data-not-this="hello">Three</div>
```

P.S. в моем комментарии к вопросу (ссылка на JSFiddle) содержится ошибка, кто заметил - тот молодец =)

Comment: Я уже добавил данную конструкцию в свой проект) Плохо конечно что он пробегает все элементы, лишняя нагрузка, но добавлять классы ко всему тоже не лучшая идея. Пока оставлю так, спасибо!

Comment: Да, я именно поэтому я указал, что данное решение - далеко не лучшее просто из-за сложности алгоритма: взять все элементы -> пробежаться по всем элементам, сравнивая атрибут -> применить нужное. Но Вам виднее, что лучше в конкретной ситуации :)